# In jquery what does $('<div></div>') do?

Tags: jquery

I was implementing a jqueryui modal dialog box and a [related blog](http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/08/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/) showed a way of implementing it that worked but I don't understand what `$("<div></div>")` is actually doing. Is this creating a blank div element to use? Is this a safe way of implementing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's equivalent to `document.createElement('DIV')`.

You can look at the [jQuery source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js). Look for the comment:

```
// Handle HTML strings
```

And you'll see how it works.

The `<div>` created is empty, has no attributes, and is not attached to the DOM.

It's more common to see it written as:

```
$('<div />')
```

...but not functionally different.

Often it's chained with a method like [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/), to insert it into the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

It's creating a blank div to use.  I don't see why it wouldn't be considered safe.  It's valid markup.  What concerns do you have about it specifically?

Answer (score 1):

It is safe but kind of outdated, this is better to use:

```
$("<div/>");
```

or optionally, you can predefine its content, event handlers etc.:

```
$("<div/>",{
  "html"  : "some content",
  "click" : function(){
    //do something.
  }
});
```